# Arithmetic mean vhdl

Tags: vhdl

im trying to create element that would make an arithmetic mean. i have one input vector in all data should be written. and one clock input to change our input value. i looked  in the internet but couldnt find result to help me to solve my problem. here is my code it works very espetial - it just works for first "some" results, and i could not understand the result. i work in Quartus 9.1. please help))

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
entity serArifmet is
generic ( r: integer :=8;
b: integer :=4);

port ( w: in signed (b-1 downto 0);
clk: in STD_LOGIC;
res: out signed (2*b-1 downto 0);
qqq: out signed(4*b-1 downto 0);
a: out signed (2*b-1 downto 0) );

end serArifmet;
architecture Arch_neuron_one of serArifmet is
type weights is array (1 to r) of signed (b-1 downto 0);
begin
process (clk, w)
variable weight: weights;
variable ost:signed(4*b-1 downto 0);
variable prod, acc, zzz: signed (2*b-1 downto 0);
variable prod2: signed (b-1 downto 0);
variable k:signed(7 downto 0);
variable eee: signed (3 downto 0);

begin
k:="00000001";
if (clk'event and clk='1') then
weight :=w & weight (1 to r-1);
end if;

acc := (others => '0');
for j in 1 to r loop
acc := acc + weight(j);
zzz:= (acc)/ k;
ost:=acc-zzz*k;
k:=k+1;

end loop;
a <= acc;

res<= zzz;
qqq<= ost;

end process;
end Arch_neuron_one;
```

[image]

Comment: What is an example of where it doesn't work?

Comment: when i use vector waveform file to check it gives me wrong results.

Comment: Ok, what is a *specific* example?  i.e. {input, expected output, actual output}.

Comment: hear is screenshot of my results(actually i dont understand them, but i think they are wrong)

Comment: Why do you think they are wrong?  Show us exactly where on the waveform you think it's wrong and what you'd expect to be there.  Expecting the reader to decode, interpret and figure it all out for themselves is a recipe for not getting many answers, as few of us have time to dedicate to that, when there are other questions for which the actual problem is clearer...

Comment: I think it works wrong because it don't count Arithmetic mean well.

Comment: if you look to the diagram youll see that it don't make division well. I think its because of k counter. I tryied to make division to the exact number(3,9,8 for example and it works). I don't what it can be

Answer (score 0):

You should remove 'w' from the sensitivity list and put the accum code inside the if (clk) statement.

Since 'w' and 'clk' are in the sensitivity list, the accum code will be evaluated each time w or clk changes.  So it is probably being evaluated twice.

If you are actually trying to synthesize this, realize that the loop will unroll into a potentially deep and huge adder.  As for the divide, it is an expensive operation that should ideally be avoided and may not even synthesize.  If you must divide, it should be limited to powers of two, or be precomputed - calculate 1/N then implement it as a multiply.  That is, x/4 = .25*x.  If you have a bunch of N's, precompute them all then select the one you need.